# Somar valores de inputs dinâmicos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso exibir o total de um "item valor x quantidade" em um paragrafo de um formulário dinâmico, esse formulário tem um botão que ao clicar cria outra div para preencher.

Consegui fazer com a div fica pegar o valor e mostrar mas quando vou para div criada dinamicamente não aparece.

```js
function calculo() {

  $('.totaldoValor2').each(function(i) {
    var valor = parseInt(document.querySelector(".valorUnitario").value, 10)
    var unidade = parseInt(document.querySelector(".qtd").value, 10)
    var total = valor * unidade;
    console.log(total);

    document.querySelector('.totaldoValor2').innerHTML = total

  })

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="despesas1 linha">
  <button type="button" class="remove"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>

  <select name="" id="">
    <option value="">Hospedagem</option>
    <option value="">Pedágio</option>
    <option value="">Alimentação</option>
    <option value="">Combustivel</option>
    <option value="">Outra</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="">
  <input type="text" name="valorUnitario" class="valorUnitario" onblur="calculo()">
  <input type="text" name="qtd" class="qtd" onblur="calculo()">
  <p name="totalValor" value=" " disabled class="totaldoValor2"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Consegui resolver.

```
function teste(){

    $('.linha').each(function (){
        console.log(this);

        // pega os valores dos inputs 

        var qtd = $(this).find('input[name=quantidade]').val()
        var val = $(this).find('input[name=valor_unitario]').val();
        var total = parseFloat(qtd) * parseFloat(val);

        //tratamento do NaN

        if(isNaN(total)){
            $(this).find('input[name=valor_total]').val(" ").html(" ")
        }else{
            $(this).find('input[name=valor_total]').val(total).html(total)
        }
        

       
    });

    // validação input    
    $('.linha').each(function (){
        console.log(this);

        var total1 =  $(this).find('input[name=valor_total]').val()
        
        if(total1 >= 200){
            $(this).addClass( "selected" ).hasClass("linha");
                    
        }       
    });
}
```

Comment: @Augusto Vasques poderia me explicar o motivo de retirar o "Boa tarde!" , isso atrapalha em alguma coisa na pesquisa?

Desculpe a pergunta mas sou novo aqui

Comment: Sim posso explicar. Porque não somos uma rede social ou fórum ou grupo de discussão. O Stack Overflow é um site de perguntas e resposta técnicas sobre linguagem de programação e nosso [código de conduta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) estabelece que nas publicações não devem ser feitos cumprimentos, agradecimentos, ser feito o uso de assinaturas e  frases de efeito.

Comment: É um comportamento já [estabelecido pela comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/846/sauda%c3%a7%c3%b5es-e-agradecimentos), pode parecer que não mas o caminho entre  [*Boa tarde* para um *Fala ai seus locos* ou *E ai bando de FDPs* é curto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/44/teoria-das-janelas-partidas). Fora o fato que é num site de alcance mundial cumprimentar pelo horário é  ruído comunicação temos usuários em todos os fusos horários, bom dia para um é boa noite para outro.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Entendi, obrigado.